# Add newline character to file

Tags: shell-script, sed

Hi Guys i need to change the below single line string using a shell script

```
{1:F01NESWSZM0AXXX1111111111} {2:I940BBRUBEBBXXXXN} {3:{108:400MSOG161200FRO}} {4: :20:400MSOG161200FRO :25:1xxxxxxxx65 :28C:7 :60F:D160429EUR423431,51 :61:1604280428DR300001,NONREF//REFABH09 INCOMING F 1 PARMALT ROUTH AFR :62F:D160429EUR423431,51 :64:D160429EUR423431,51 -}
```

TO

```
{1:F01NESWSZM0AXXX1111111111} {2:I940BBRUBEBBXXXXN} {3:{108:400MSOG161200FRO}} {4: 
:20:400MSOG161200FRO 
:25:1xxxxxxxx65 
:28C:7 
:60F:D160429EUR423431,51 
:61:1604280428DR300001,NONREF//REFABH09 INCOMING F 1 PARMALT ROUTH AFR 
:62F:D160429EUR423431,51 
:64:D160429EUR423431,51 -}
```

I was thinking of using sed but the strings are more than 1 when a newline should be added before the character.

The delimiter for a new line are

```
:20:
:25:
:28C:
:60F:
:64:
```

How can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use "alternatives" using the `\|`:

```
sed 's/\(:\(20\|25\|28C\|60F\|64\):\)/\n\1/g'
```

Comment: Am not sure where am getting it wrong am using sed 's/\(:\(20\|25\|28C\|60F\|64\):\)/\n\1/g' SWZIN7>nick  where SWZIN7 is a file with the string to be formatted but it not working

Comment: Am doing this on AIX

Comment: I'm not sure how sed works on an AIX. Do you have Perl installed?

Comment: This should work on borne shell right?

Comment: `sed` is an external tool, not part of the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
sed 's/ :/\n:/g' long.txt
```

Comment: when i use it it replacing with a n and a newline